# Echo text after an amount of time

Tags: php

Hello im trying to make a logout session.. my problem is that its not visible if im logged out or not after an amount of time so im trying to write out a text to let the user now its logged out..
As i understood from now i do not get logged out until i update my site again, so i want to echo out the text without updating my site.. is this possible?!

Here is my homemade code

```
if (isset($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']) && (time() - $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] > 20)) {
include("logout.php");
echo "you have been logged out";
}
$_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time(); 
}
```

My logout.php aswell

```
session_start();
session_destroy();
header("Location:index.php");
```

Some help and advice would be great!

Comment: You have to use something client side to either force a redirect, perform an ajax call in the background or display a message to the client saying time is coming up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, through PHP alone, you have to wait until the user makes a call to PHP.  Or, you can use Ajax to make periodic calls to PHP and then redirect if they are logged out.  Try to find a good tutorial on this, since it is greater than the scope an answer allows in this context.

Here is one that I found with a quick google search, though i confess, I only briefly reviewed it.  It does seem to discuss what is needed here; i can't verify that the method works, but the parts are all there.

http://www.vijayjoshi.org/2008/12/08/automatic-session-timeoutlogout-using-php-and-ajax/